# Counting the number of columns that meet a logical criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting create a count column that summarizes the number of columns within each row of a dataframe satisfy some logical criteria. I have figured out a `for` loop for it, but I can't seem to come up with a `dplyr` or other such answer that would make it simple to use on a number of different columns or if the columns were shifted.

```
#### 
x <- matrix(rep(rnorm(n = 100, mean = 7, sd = 3),16),nrow = 100,ncol=16)
colnames(x) <- paste0("foo",1:16)
library(dplyr)
x <- as.data.frame(x)

## Something that  works
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  x[i,"Over9"] <- sum(subset(x[i,1:4] > 9))
}

## Attempt to make it smarter
y <- x %>% select(foo1:foo4) %>% 
  mutate("Over9" = rowSums(which(x[,.] > 9)))
```

I've tried a number of different solutions but just have consistently failed.

Comment: Why not just `rowSums(x[1:4] > 9)` if you're going to use `rowSums`?

Comment: @thelatemail I very well could (i didn't know about it until after I wrote the `for` loop) I'm trying to add the functionality like the that of the `select()` function so I don't need to use the actual column numbers.

Comment: There's little need to use `dplyr` for this - `rowSums(x[paste0("foo",1:4)] > 9)` for example if you want to select by name instead of column position.

Comment: @thelatemail Very true, I forgot I could call columns like that. Thanks.